# Using sheetjs to style form headers - where do I add cssStyles to the tabulator xlsx download function?

Tags: tabulator, sheetjs

I am trying to make the headers of the exported xlsx tabulator table bold using sheetjs.

They provide documentation to style these fields and say to use `cssStyles: true`, but where do I add this in the download for function using tabulator?

There's not much documentation on how to get these to work with eachother even though it is recommended!

Any help would be amazing!!

```
table.download("xlsx", "data.xlsx",{
    documentProcessing:function(workbook){
        //workbook - sheetJS workbook object
        cssStyles: true, <--- Would I add it here??

        let ws = workbook.Sheets[workbook.SheetNames[0]]

            // Reset range to be correct!
            function update_sheet_range(ws) {
              let range = {s:{r:Infinity, c:Infinity},e:{r:0,c:0}};
              Object.keys(ws).filter(function(x) { return x.charAt(0) !== '!'; }).map(XLSX.utils.decode_cell).forEach(function(x) {
                range.s.c = Math.min(range.s.c, x.c); range.s.r = Math.min(range.s.r, x.r)
                range.e.c = Math.max(range.e.c, x.c); range.e.r = Math.max(range.e.r, x.r)
              });
              ws['!ref'] = XLSX.utils.encode_range(range)
            }
            update_sheet_range(ws)

            // Now set range to be correct range!
            let range = XLSX.utils.decode_range(ws['!ref'])

            // Freeze top row
            ws['!freeze'] = 'A2'

            // Add filters to headers
            ws['!autofilter'] = { ref: range }

            // Make all columns auto width
            if (!ws['!cols']) ws['!cols'] = []
            for (let C = 0; C <= 16383; ++C) { // 0 = "A", 16383 = "XFD"
              if(!ws['!cols'][C]) ws['!cols'][C] = { auto: 1 } // default width
            }

            // Bold the headers - THIS ISN'T WORKING :(
            range.s.r = 0; range.e.r = 0; // restrict to the first row
            XLSX.utils.sheet_set_range_style(ws, "A1:B1", {
              bold: true
              cellStyles: true, <--- Or do I add it here?
            })

            console.log(ws)

            return workbook
    }
});
```